# How to pass url parameter in phonegap and jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am developing a app using jquery mobile and phonegap. I need to pass a url parameter from jqm page to another page.This jqm code is wokring fine.

Page 1

```
<a data-icon="maps" data-role="button" href="page2.html?id=test">Click</a>
```

Page 2

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
alert($.urlParam('id'));
```

But when I add the same in to phonegap its not working. Any ideas how to use this in phonegap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this method. More easier for you.

Page 1

html

```
<a id="mapButton" data-icon="maps" data-role="button" >Click</a>
```

javascript

```
$("#mapButton").click(function() {
    sessionStorage.param1 = "test";
    window.location.replace("page2.html");
});
```

Page 2

```
alert(sessionStorage.param1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the issue I ran into here (http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/2/24/Getting-URL-parameters-in-a-jQuery-Mobile-page), essentially, jQM stores the URL in $(this).data("url"). You can get this value in your pageshow event, split on ?, and parse the query string there.

Comment: I have added this in page 1. 
<a href="test.html?id=Setmil">Structure</a> 
Second page this.
 <script>
  $("#test").live("pageshow", function(e) {
 var query = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
 query = query.replace("id=","");
 alert(id);
});
</script>
I am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First - do you see *any* alert?

Comment: Then this means your pageshow code is incorrect, agreed? Or you have an error. Can you confirm no error shows in the console?

Comment: What I'd recommend is this - instead of a script block on each page, take your code and put it into one main JS file. Load that from index.html. Since jQM uses AJAX to load other pages, the second page will still be in the same context and your JS will still be available. Try that. Your first goal is to ensure pageshow properly runs for the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I just created a jQuery Mobile plug-in and put it [here on Github](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler). It allows you to pass parameters via the URL and maintains them in the URL so that page refreshes and direct URL navigation works fine.

Let me know if it helps and good luck!